# OnCreateOptionsMenu Null Pointer when resuming application

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am getting a null pointer exception when the app has been in the background and has to create the main activity again when brought to the foreground. The code below is for the overridden activity method onCreateOptionsMenu where I do a few null checks which should cause the app to restart with the SplashActivity in case of lost data. The debug build works fine but when I build the release version I consistently get the exception below after bringing the app to the foreground when it has been stopped showing that there is an Unknown Source for the menu parameter calling a method .a.g() which I do not understand. I don't think it is a Proguard issue.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    if (agencyManager == null || menu == null || getMenuInflater() == null) {
        // If agencyManager data lost (possibly caused by backgrounding the app for a long period of time),
        // launch the splash activity, pass through any potential stop selected
        // from a notification, and finish.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
        if (stopSelectedFromNotification != -1) {
            intent.putExtra(STOP_ID_EXTRA, stopSelectedFromNotification);
            intent.putExtra(ROUTE_ID_EXTRA, routeSelectedFromNotification);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // Don't animate the transition
        finish();
        return false;
    }

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    MenuItem twitter = menu.findItem(R.id.action_news);
    twitter.setVisible(!agencyManager.getTwitter().equals(""));



    MenuItem website = menu.findItem(R.id.action_website);
    website.setVisible(!agencyManager.getURL().equals(""));

    MenuItem faq = menu.findItem(R.id.action_faq);
    faq.setVisible(!agencyManager.getFaqURL().equals(""));

    MenuItem riding = menu.findItem(R.id.action_riding);
    riding.setVisible(!agencyManager.getRidingURL().equals(""));

    MenuItem code = menu.findItem(R.id.action_code);
    code.setVisible(!agencyManager.getCodeURL().equals(""));

    MenuItem fares = menu.findItem(R.id.action_fares);
    fares.setVisible(agencyManager.getFareJSON().length()>5 || agencyManager.getFareText().length()>5);

    /**
    //Webschedule view option added to menu, will be visible if schedule table supported
    MenuItem webSchedule = menu.findItem(R.id.action_web_schedule);
    final Route route = mapUiManager.selectedRoute;

    webSchedule.setVisible(agencyManager.useScheduleTable());
     **/


    MenuItem settings = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);


    // Display the welcome info screens the first time the app is run
    displayWelcomeInfoFirstRun();

    return true;
}
```

Log:

```
01-18 12:48:28.872  31937-31937/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.company.android.packagename, PID: 31937
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String edu.company.android.packagename.a.g()' on a null object reference
            at edu.company.android.packagename.MapActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2850)
            at android.support.v4.app.aa.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.l.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.f.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.m.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:567)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:939)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:271)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: @JacobFrancis: Please disable proguard in your project first, to verify issue line number, other option is to configure proguard setting which provide original line number. `'java.lang.String edu.company.android.packagename.a.g()`

Comment: Oh thank you for the tip, I honestly did not realize that Proguard obfuscated the code.

Comment: Glad, that i could help, kindly accept that as answer if helped.

Comment: I have tried many suggestions online but I cannot figure out how to configure proguard to show line numbers and not obfuscate the method names. I am certain that proguard is the underlying issue though since there is no crash if it is completely disabled.

Comment: In proguard-rules.pro file, add this: **-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,SourceFile,LineNumberTable**  LineNumberTable will do trick for you, other attributes are helpful too.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this later, you only need `-keepattributes Exceptions,SourceFile,LineNumberTable` to provide specific crash information.